# Seven segment Scoreboard single digit dataset

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a dataset with seven segment scoreboard display digits since I want to train a neural network to classify such digits. Right now I'm trying to create my own dataset but it would be a nice shortcut if I could use an already existing one. I've found some dataset with seven segment digits from LCD display's from calculators and such, but that's not what I want. I'm looking for single digits in seven segment font from e.g ice hockey or soccer scoreboards.

Comment: internet search? https://github.com/SachaIZADI/Seven-Segment-OCR

Comment: please link the datasets you found, so that any potential answers don't propose the same ones